# Vb.net how to add value of array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

This is what it looks like :

```
Dim a As Integer

    a = ComboBox1.SelectedItem()

    Label1.Text += a
```

i want to add all the value that selected from combobox1

Comment: Please be more specific when post a question, poor explanation leads to closing the question and/or to gain down vote

Comment: i wan to add all the value that has been selected from combobox1 how can i do that ?

Comment: you want to add the selected items to a label ?

Comment: all the selected for example 

1 + 3 + 5
1,3,5 are selecteditem from combobox

Comment: what kind of objects are displayed in your combobox ?

Comment: just a integer value

Comment: Do you have checkbox in combobox ? or you are planning to append selected values into label on each selection ?

Comment: dont have checkbox in combobox, im planning to put all the value of selected item from combo box to label

Comment: check the answer, comment under the answer if you need any improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly following is the piece of code that OP is looking for,

```
 Dim intVal As Integer
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged

    If Label1.Text = String.Empty Then
        Label1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        intVal = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    Else
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text & "+" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        intVal = intVal + Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: how can i total this ?

Comment: how do you plan to get the total, in a button click after selecting required values from the combox or what ?

Comment: in this code the ouput will be 

1+3+5+5 (just random numbers)
how can i total this ?

Comment: it keeps recording the record but didnt sum it

Comment: what is the final output of `intVal` after all selection?

Comment: i tried to put it 
label1.text = intVal + Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
it keeps multiply every selected value

Comment: i also tried
label1.text = intval 
it also keeps record frm selected item

Comment: I haven't made any relationship with the label and the declared object `intVal `

Comment: see, `Label1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString` and `Label1.Text = Label1.Text & "+" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString` will give you this (ex. `Label1.text="1+2+3+5"`), right?

Comment: yup how can i add that ?

Comment: its the same just keep recording with "+"